# lookup between asset and case

Tags: soql

I am trying to find count of cases based on asset:

[image]

```
SELECT COUNT() From Case where Asset.Number = '100'
```

But it is throwing errror...

Comment: please always add the error message, if you are receiving any.

Answer (score 0):

This is because we don't have any field with API name `number` on Asset. You need to fix that API name. I tried with Name field and it works.

```
[SELECT COUNT() From Case where Asset.Name = '100']
```

Also in your case you need this query

```
[SELECT COUNT(ID) From Case Group BY AssetId];
```

Comment: SELECT Id,CaseNumber, Asset.Name From Case . I tried like this but getting No such relation 'Asset' on entity 'Case'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: @Kiran I run this query in my org and din't face any issue. Where are you running this. Also check my updated answer.

Comment: Asset is a child of Account Object in Data Model...Hence error i am getting... ANy alternative way of doing this

Comment: @kiran, the field is hidden from FLS for the user you're testing with?

Comment: @Kiran you can query this from case as well. both query are working in my org.

Comment: @kiran if its solve your problem you can accept this answer.